# Amazon EMR: Only start new scheduled job if previous job has finished

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have a AWS EMR cluster job which runs every 2 hours. I have set up a schedule using cloudWatch job to run every two hours.

But sometimes the next job (which runs after 2 hour from previous one) starts when previous one is not finished as it sometimes take more than 2 hours to completed depending on data to be processed.

I need some configuration by which I could prevent next job to be started if previous job is running.
I tried but couldn't found any set up. Can anyone knows how to do that please?

Comment: Hi, Anyone has any resolution to my question above ?

Answer (score 0):

Add them as EMR steps. EMR steps run sequentially by default(Unless you change the concurrency setting)